# Properly create Java JAR

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I am using IntelliJ to create a variant of the Java WorldWind application. When I build the JAR artifact in IntelliJ I can see my DLLs and SOs in the top-level directory of the JAR. However, when I try to execute it, it complains it can't see these libraries that are inside the JAR (tried both Windows and Linux, thus being why I include SOs and DLLs).

What do I need to do to get it to see these libraries?

This is my first time creating an executable JAR, so sorry for the vagueness, I'm not quite sure what information is important. Please ask me any questions necessary to better understand this problem, and I will answer them.

---

Edit:

```
Catched FileNotFoundException: D:\code\Animator\animator\out\artifacts\Animator_jar\Animator-natives-windows-i586.jar (The system cannot find the file specified), 
while addNativeJarLibsImpl(
    classFromJavaJar class com.jogamp.common.os.Platform, 
    classJarURI jar:file:/D:/code/Animator/animator/out/artifacts/Animator_jar/Animator.jar!/com/jogamp/common/os/Platform.class, 
    nativeJarBaseName Animator-natives-windows-i586.jar): 
    [ file:/D:/code/Animator/animator/out/artifacts/Animator_jar/Animator.jar -> 
      file:/D:/code/Animator/animator/out/artifacts/Animator_jar/ ] + 
    Animator-natives-windows-i586.jar -> 
    slim: jar:file:/D:/code/Animator/animator/out/artifacts/Animator_jar/Animator-natives-windows-i586.jar!/

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: D:\code\Animator\animator\out\artifacts\Animator_jar\gluegen-rt.dll
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibraryInternal(JNILibLoaderBase.java:551)
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.access$000(JNILibLoaderBase.java:64)
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase$DefaultAction.loadLibrary(JNILibLoaderBase.java:96)
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibrary(JNILibLoaderBase.java:414)
    at com.jogamp.common.os.DynamicLibraryBundle$GlueJNILibLoader.loadLibrary(DynamicLibraryBundle.java:388)
    at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform$1.run(Platform.java:209)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:179)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.<clinit>(GLProfile.java:82)
    at au.gov.ga.worldwind.animator.application.AnimatorConfiguration.<clinit>(AnimatorConfiguration.java:46)
    at au.gov.ga.worldwind.animator.application.Animator.<clinit>(Animator.java:205)
```

---

As far as the structure of the JAR, I don't know how to show other than a screenshot of the JAR in 7-Zip:

[image: JAR Contents]

Comment: Hi Todd, Can you show the error message and the structures of the project and the jar?

Comment: I believe I have edited my post with the requested information.

Answer (score 0):

In the image we can see that the name of the jar is: Animator.jar, but intelliJ is searching for: Animator-natives-windows-i586.jar. You must go to Module Settings - Artifacts and change the OutputDirectory to: D:\code\Animator\animator\out\artifacts\Animator_jar
Then check the name of the artifact to match the path and the name of the file.
 [image]

The image added by me is an example.